# How to Trace a Java flow from Method to method using Java

Tags: java, trace

I want to trace a Java flow whenever there is a Exception happening . I mean Like Consider

Method1 -> Method2 -> Method3 -> Method4 -> Error Came in Method 4 while processing argument1, let’s say we find it invalid.

Then, we could have a response element which looks like below:

“DebugInfo” : “Method1|Method2|Method3|Method4 - Error Came in Method 4 while processing argument1. It is invalid because destination does not support HAL”

Comment: That's what a stack trace does. Just log the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what happens using the method [getStackTrace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()):

> Provides programmatic access to the stack trace information printed by printStackTrace(). Returns an array of stack trace elements, each representing one stack frame. **The zeroth element of the array** (assuming the array's length is non-zero) **represents the top of the stack, which is the last method invocation in the sequence**. Typically, this is the point at which this throwable was created and thrown. The last element of the array (assuming the array's length is non-zero) represents the bottom of the stack, which is the first method invocation in the sequence.

Note that the order is exactly the opposite as you need (see the bold part)

So you can do something like

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = exception.getStackTrace();
for (int i = elements.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   System.out.println(elements[i].getMethodName());
}
```

You need only to add some templating to that to get exactly what you need.

Note that printing (or exporting) only the method name is not enough because generally you have a stack moving through different classes so it is better to print class name and method name. But for larger methods is useful also to know at which row it happened, so... why don't use a simple `exception.printStackTrace()` that does exactly what you need?

Comment: I have to respond to my client with the error message in the format I mentioned already and to respond I need to have these Traces and yes thanks Davide , I used this  StackTraceElement class and made some changes to match my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Thread has all the knowledge about its stack trace,

so this could help

```
Arrays.stream(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())
        .map(StackTraceElement::toString)
        .filter(element -> element.startsWith("com.<YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME>"))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\t-->\t"));
```